# Python pandas can't execute

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I got problem with importing pandas and statsmodels.
But importing these modules work fines with command line.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code i tested:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
Y = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4]
X = range(1,8)
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(Y,X)
results = model.fit()
print(results.params)
```

Comment: it works fine with command line but fails when? Which code and which interpreter does your traceback relates to?

Comment: You most likely use different interpreters for python in command line and for executed python code.